# x86 - examining the memory

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86

So assume I want to examine an offset of a register in memory in x86-64 (AT&T style) in gdb.

I know I can do `x $rbp` and I can view assume the next ten items as follows: `x/10s $rbp`. But how would I just access the 10th offset for example? Or is there no way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x/10s $rbp + 0xa
```

maybe? I can't check since I haven't linux anymore though